# iOS background operations - Is it possible to perform network request subsequent to significant location updates?

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7, location, cllocationmanager

I am building an app, that has location updates enabled in the background, for this I am using an instance of `CLLocationManager` with the following code:

```
self.coreLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.coreLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

I implemented its delegate callback `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)locationManager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`, in which I trigger a network request to Google in order to reverse geocode the coordinates and retrieve the address of the location.

This does work very well if the app is in the foreground, but in the background it it doesn't seem to work. I have difficulties debugging it for testing as well, because I can't access the logs when the app is in the background (so I used *Mixpanel*, an analytics framework to capture the location updates as events, but apparently they don't work either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive significant location change updates in the background you need to restart location services when your app is launched into the background - your delegate methods won't be called unless you do this.

From the [Location And Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW16) -

> If you are monitoring regions or using the significant-change location
>   service in your app, there are situations where you must start
>   location services at launch time. Apps using those services can be
>   terminated and subsequently relaunched when new location events
>   arrive. Although the app itself is relaunched, location services are
>   not started automatically. When an app is relaunched because of a
>   location update, the launch options dictionary passed to your
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method contains the
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key. The presence of that key
>   signals that new location data is waiting to be delivered to your app.
>   To obtain that data, you must create a new CLLocationManager object
>   and restart the location services that you had running prior to your
>   app’s termination. When you restart those services, the location
>   manager delivers all pending location updates to its delegate.

Also, when you are launched into the background you should not perform network operations unless you request additional execution time.  From the Location and Maps Programming Guide again -

> Because your app is in the background, it must do minimal work and
>   avoid any tasks (such as querying the network) that might prevent it
>   from returning before the allocated time expires. If it does not, your
>   app will be terminated. If an iOS app needs more time to process the
>   location data, it can request more background execution time using the
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: method of the
>   UIApplication class.